# Using Metadata to view as conventional folder structure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can Metadata be used to generate a view as the conventional folder drill-down?

I have a list with metadata for different projects, releases, content type etc and I would like to view them in folder structure with different hierarchies, i.e. using projects--> releases--> content-type as well as release --> projects --> content-type.

I have asked the same question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8aadea00-8e6e-4c68-b37a-fa36d125c31b/using-metadata-to-generate-view-as-conventional-folder-structure?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)